# how to determine driver for motherboard ethernet adapter

Tags: drivers, troubleshooting, network-adapter

I have an older machine on which the OS (w2k) got corrupted. As a result, it no longer can find the driver for its ethernet adapter. The install-new-hardware wizard just identifies the device with a yellow question mark, from which the only information to be had is "Code 28" and "the driver for the device is not installed".

Obviously I could just install a 2nd adapter, but I kind of want the on-board one working. There are no distinguishing marks on the motherboard (unless they're underneath) and it might not be possible to find the CD with the drivers for it.

Is there a way to find out what driver is needed? Perhaps a utility that can recognize different adapter register footprints, or something, and at least cough up a name of a driver I could go and find?

Comment: Try this software...http://www.zhangduo.com/udi.html

Answer (score 4):

I like to look at [pcidatabase.com](http://pcidatabase.com). This often gives the vendor and model allowing you to search for drivers at least knowing what you're looking for. All you need is the hardware ID which you can get from Deivce manager.
Simply Right click on the item, select properties. Select the tab details and select Hardware ID's from the drop down box.

Comment: Wow... I read the first line of this and then wrote my own answer to cover the stuff you left out... but of course you didn't leave it out I am just an idiot LOL.